# Who are these villains named 'Control' in Captain America and the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, video-games

At one point in the final level of the arcade game, *[Captain America and the Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America_and_The_Avengers)* (1991), the player/s encounter two "boss" villains -- either robot or cyborg characters -- both named 'Control.' Does anyone know their history or more about them?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I believe those characters are based on **[the Controller/Basil Sandhurst](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Basil_Sandhurst_(Earth-616))**, a supervillain who first appeared in *[Iron Man Vol. 1 #12](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_1_12)* (April, 1969).

[image]

He's primarily an Iron Man foe, but has also fought other superheroes, such as the original Captain Marvel ([Mar-Vell](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mar-Vell_(Earth-616))) and Captain America.

For additional background on his origin and powers, here are a couple of excerpts from one of his entries in the *Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe*.

> HISTORY: Bedridden by meningitis as a child, Basil Sandhurst became obsessed with controlling every aspect of his surroundings, an obsession which, in adulthood, led to his downfall as a scientist when his refusal to obey ethical constraints resulted in him being barred from most research facilities. Contemptuous of the supposedly "menial" work he was assigned at Cordco, Sandhurst became subject to fits of rage, and in the course of calming him, his brother Vincent inadvertently triggered a laboratory explosion, leaving Basil scarred and crippled. When the guilt-ridden Vincent outfitted their Maine home with an automated lab, Basil bonded a super-strong exoskeleton to his disabled body, powered by his own cerebral energies, and, via slave discs empowered by his Absorbatron device, those of the people around him.
>
> [...]
>
> ABILITIES/ACCESSORIES: The Controller wears a stainless steel exoskeleton, microsurgically and permanently affixed to his body, that grants him mobility, as well as, via the channeling of his personal cerebral energies or latent psionic power, sufficient superhuman strength to lift at least half a ton. He uses "slave discs" to control others, up to several dozen at a time, via direct psionic link; he can siphon as much as 85% of his victim's cerebral energies by remotely converting these energies into extradimensional radiation transmitted directly into his exoskeleton's microcircuited power converters, which then re-convert the radiation into energy he can use to magnify his exoskeleton's strength up to a hundredfold. The energies can also be channeled to provide the Controller with such psionic abilities as telepathy, levitation and telekinesis, as well as any special abilities possessed by his victims. It is not known how many discs he customarily carries on his person, but he apparently has no means of producing more without elaborate laboratory conditions, limiting his ability to seize control of people in his vicinity. The Controller's access to his victim's energies vanishes as soon as his slave discs are removed, although he can psionically control unsuspecting or "weak-willed" subjects even without his discs.
>
> The Controller originally required his Absorbatron device to effectively derive power from his victims and, although it is no longer necessary for such a purpose, he still occasionally employs it to better handle large numbers of victims and to store siphoned energy for later use. He sometimes uses microchips that when surgically implanted in pre-selected victims, allows him to control them without the risk of easy removal. He flies via boot-jets and has employed image inducers, stun mists, and other technology as needed; for a time, he employed mind-controlled cyborgs called Berserkers, whom he granted superhuman strength and durability via a combination of cybernetic, hormonal, and chemical augmentation.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_2)* (May, 2008)</sub>